Reason for wildcard certificate issue with Apache HTTP Client and Java 8
I get an SSLPeerUnverifiedException after switching from HTTP to HTTPS which I don't understand since the wildcard certificate should work for the URL.
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <abc.lan.corp.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.lan.corp.com]
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.client.SAPDownloader.download(SAPDownloader.java:31)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.client.download.DownloadClient.getSAPInformation(DownloadClient.java:62)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.client.download.DownloadClient.executeDelegate(DownloadClient.java:33)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.client.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:23)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin.lambda$4(SapSyncMixin.java:93)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin$$Lambda$32/0x0000000000000000.apply(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
 at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:497)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:487)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:241)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
 at org.jooq.lambda.SeqImpl.collect(SeqImpl.java:190)
 at org.jooq.lambda.Seq.toList(Seq.java:9194)
 at org.jooq.lambda.SeqImpl.toList(SeqImpl.java:558)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin.runSync(SapSyncMixin.java:99)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin$$Lambda$5/0x0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin.runSync(SapSyncMixin.java:61)
 at lan.corp.com.sapconnector.SapSyncMixin.runSync(SapSyncMixin.java:54)
 at org.corp.com.domino.abrechnungs.agent.SapSyncAgentBase.NotesMain(SapSyncAgentBase.java:15)
 at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)


The used Java runtime version is 1.8.0_302-b08 and the failing https request is made with Apache HTTP client 4.5.9
Accessing the same server with Google Chrome reports the certificate as valid with same URL.
Any ideas?

Posting the stack trace would allow us to see if the certificate checking code belongs to JRE or to Apache htpclient.

Please post a complete HttpClient wire / context log of the session and I will take a look https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.4.x/logging.html

@Robert stack trace added to my question

Upgrade to Apache HttpClient 4.5.14 or 5.4.1

This is a known problem and should be fixed in 4.5.12 or newer see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2047 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2055
